# can i convert pdf to xml/JSON using itext?

Tags: itext

I have a requirement to convert PDF to XML/JSON to get the properties of the text, can I do that using itext?

If so, please let me know which class, that you are aware of, can do that.

I tried looking into the API but could not find any method.

Comment: Define the "properties of the text." Which XML schema are you looking for? Is your PDF Tagged (in that case, you could use the PDF tags for the XML tags) or is it an ordinary PDF (in that case, give up all hope)? If you want JSON, what would be the structure of the data? Your question is totally unclear. It should be closed for that reason.

Comment: Straight out of the box with some kind of convertor-class or method? Nope, and good luck finding one. As Bruno alluded in his comment, it isn't exactly easy and depending on the pdf in question, it can be a downright nightmare. As a toolbox that gives you access to the innards of pdfs, iText can be the foundation of your solution, but you'll have to do some major work yourself.